# MFC Control "CVSListBox" - How to use the interface "AddButton"?

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there anybody could tech me how to use the interface "AddButton" of the MFC control? "CVSListBox"? I wrote the below code, and the new buttons have showed on the control successful, but I can't respond its ON_BN_CLICKED event. Could you tell me why? thanks.

```
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_AWSPORTIMPORT, &CPgTestAwsPortfolio::OnBnClickedBtnAwsportimport)

    void CPgTestAwsPortfolio::OnBnClickedBtnAwsportimport()
    {
        int xx = 100;
    }

CPortCaseListBox m_lbAwsPortCases;
    m_pgTestAwsPort.m_lbAwsPortCases.AddButton(IDB_AFXBARRES_NEW, _T("Import"), 0, 0, IDC_BTN_AWSPORTIMPORT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is different here. 
All Buttons are handled internally in the CVSListBox class.

See CVSListBoxBaseBase::OnCommand override.

1. When a button sends a WM_COMMAND it is intercepted by CVSListBoxBaseBase::OnCommand
2. When the id is member of the internal button list of the ist Control the virtual function OnClickButton is executed.
3. GetButtonID might help you to convert the Position into the ID.

Note OnClickButton receives the number of the button, not the id.

So the parent never receives any notification of this Buttons. It is all handled in the virtual functions of CVSListBox.

The documentation is incomplete because the Base class isn't described and document.

Comment: thank your for your hint, I've override the interface "OnClickButton", and it could be revived the click event. thanks a lot.